# Как распознать изменение файлов в папке на стороне сервера?

Tags: git, githooks

Как нужно настроить серверный git hook чтобы он срабатывал **только** в выбранной папке и **только** для выбранного расширения файлов?

Comment: никак не «настроить». внутри скрипта вам надо перебрать список изменяемых файлов (см. примеры в `.git/hooks/`) и делать (либо не делать) что вам там требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как нужно настроить серверный git hook чтобы он срабатывал только в выбранной папке и только для выбранного расширения файлов?

«настроить» — никак. но можно **реализовать** требуемую логику прямо в скрипте.

пример для hook-а `update` приведён в файле `hooks/update.sample` внутри хранилища. в частности, в нём указано, что скрипт вызывается с тремя аргументами:

```
# --- Command line
refname="$1"
oldrev="$2"
newrev="$3"
```

вот и воспользуемся вторым и третьим аргументом, чтобы получить список изменившихся файлов. для этого на сервере в хранилище создадим файл `hooks/update` (не забыв добавить ему биты исполнимости — `$ chmod + x hooks/update`):

```
refname="$1"
oldrev="$2"
newrev="$3"
if git diff $oldrev $newrev --name-only | grep -q '^files/exe.*'; then
  echo "что-то делаю" >&2
else
  echo "ничего не делаю" >&2
fi
```

если среди затронутых обрабатываемым коммитом файлом присутствуют файлы, подпадающие под регулярное выражение `^files/exe.*` (т.е., располагаются непосредственно в каталоге `files` рабочей копии и имеют префикс `exe.`), то пользователь, выполняющий команду `push`, получит сообщение `что-то делаю`:

```
$ mkdir files
$ touch files/exe.some
$ git add files/exe.some
$ git commit -m 'some message'
...
$ git push
...
remote: что-то делаю
...
```

а если таковых файлов нет, то сообщение будет: `ничего не делаю`.

вместо вывода сообщений подставьте требующиеся вам действия.

Comment: Спасибо за развернуый ответ!